# Solving continuity equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

What is the method of solving  these system of equations, where e is electron, and p is neutral and ion particles,with variable temperature T.

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial n_{e,p}}{\partial t}+\nabla.J_{e,p}=S_{e,p}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
J_{e,p}=-\nabla n_{e,p}D(T)_{e,p}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
S_{p,e}=\sum k(T)_{i}n_{p}n_{e}
\end{equation}

Thanks

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a *numerical method* to approximate the solutions of this differential equation?

Comment: G. Sassatelli yes I am

Comment: There are lots of numerical methods. Usually the choice depends on (a) the geometry of the problem (you do not specify what kind of boundary/boundary conditions you have), (b) how you are going to use the result (is the table of values enough, do the functions need to be continuous, will you need the derivatives as well), (c) what kind of language do you know/prefer, or maybe you need some specialized software, and finally (d) what kind of hardware you have available for computations (personal computer, cluster etc.)

Comment: There are multiple undefined terms as well as an absence of boundary conditions.